# \label not written to aux file

Tags: cross-referencing, auxiliary-files

In rare situations, when `\label` is used at the very end of a page, the result is not written to the `aux` file (I have a complicated example with the `cvmodern` class but unfortunately cannot provide a minimal example).

My question: Has anyone experience with cases when a `\label` command is not executed or the result is not written to the `aux`file?

Comment: Try to insert `\label{}` just after the numbered object which it refers to.

Comment: Please construct a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting from `\documentclass...` until `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is it a plain `\label`, or is it buried in some other macro?  If the latter, then it is possible that it is being lost in an improperly constructed/utilized macro.  A MWE would be helpful....

Comment: end of page or end of document? (latter is a lot easier to show)

Comment: Are you trying to set a label for using the last page number? Then the package `lastpage` does it for you.

Comment: The label is set (or not set) by the package cvmodern. I was not able to give a MWE because the error is only caused if the End of the Document is exactly at a pagebreak (which is the case in my long document). I am just asking if there are cases where a \label command does not write to the aux file.

Comment: @JFMeier With the standard classes (_i.e._ no unexpected 'features'), `\label` always writes to the `.aux` file. That's why an example is realaistically needed here: this could be an issue with the class you are using, but to be sure we'll need something to work with.

Comment: @JosephWright  Thanks. That is all I wanted to know.